# Purpose of nested function within memoization function is confusing me. Does someone smart understand?

Tags: python, function, recursion, nested, memoization

What is the function 'inner' doing below? Is it there just because the 'return inner' needs to be enclosed within the 'memoize_factorial' function?

```
memory = {}
def memoize_factorial(f):
    
    # This inner function has access to memory
    # and 'f'
    def inner(num): # WHAT DOES this "inner" FUNCTION DO?
        if num not in memory:
            memory[num] = f(num)
            print('result saved in memory')
        else:
            print('returning result from saved memory')
        return memory[num]

    return inner # WHAT DOES "inner" MEAN?
    
@memoize_factorial
def facto(num):
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return num * facto(num-1)

print(facto(5))
print(facto(5)) # directly coming from saved memory
```

I got this code from this Geeks for Geeks article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memoization-using-decorators-in-python/

I tried seeing if I could understand what was happening in this code like a grown up but after 45 minutes of being square brained I decided to ask smarter people with less square brains.

Comment: `return inner # WHAT DOES "inner" MEAN?`, well, `inner` is a local variable, which refers to the function you just defined right above the `return` statement

Comment: In any case, this is really too broad of a question. What, exactly, is it you don't understand about the function definition `def inner`? Do you understand how decorators work? Note, this decorator is pretty useless, since you cannot re-use it. Honestly, a really bad example of a decorator

Comment: `memoize_factorial` is used as a decorator.  (See the `@memoize_factorial`?)  That means it essentially acts as a wrapper around `facto`.  By doing `return inner`, that means anyone that calls `facto` will actually call `inner` instead.  `inner` checks to see if the parameter has already been seen.  If it hasn't, it calls the original (`f`, passed to the decorator) and stores it in memory.

Comment: It’s an okay example of a decorator IMO, it’s just named poorly — it’ll work to memoize *any* function that takes a single (hashable) argument, not just your factorial function.  If you were to take this same decorator and apply it to something else as well (maybe a recursive Fibonacci function) the interaction between the decorator and the function becomes more clear.

Comment: @Samwise it will only work for *one function* though. If I decorate `def foo(x): return x` with it, after having used it with, say, `fact(5)`, then `foo(5)` will provide wrong results (`120` instead of `5`), since it just naively memoizes based on the value of the input, using a single dict. The `memory = {}` should be **inside** `memoize_factorial` so each decorated function gets it's own memory. The name is actually fine, since it apparently is only supposed to ever memoize the factorial function

Comment: That's true, `memory = {}` should be inside the decorator function.  No reason at all for it to be global.

Comment: You should read a tutorial on Python decorators. They're practically always implemented with nested functions like this, and the tutorial will explain the logic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.